# Add transition in custom camera

Tags: ios, camera, swift4, uiviewanimationtransition

I am implementing a custom camera.
All is working perfectly.
I want to add transition while switching from front to back and vice versa.
Here is my code.

```
      @IBAction func switchCamera(_ sender: Any) {

        captureSession.beginConfiguration()
        let newDevice = (currentDevice?.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back) ? frontCamera : backCamera
        for input in captureSession.inputs {
            captureSession.removeInput(input as! AVCaptureDeviceInput)
        }
        let cameraInput:AVCaptureDeviceInput
        do {
            cameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: newDevice!)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        if captureSession.canAddInput(cameraInput) {
            captureSession.addInput(cameraInput)
        }
        currentDevice = newDevice
        captureSession.commitConfiguration()
    }
```

I want to add to add smooth animation while sided of camera are switching.(Similar to how we navigate from one ViewController to other).

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a UIView behind the camera view with clear background colour and then add transition to that view while switching the camera from back to front or vice-versa. Do it with declaring a @IBOutlet of a UIView or programmatically and then on switch use this: Hope it will help.

```
UIView.transition(with: yourView,
                     duration: 0.5,
                     options: [.transitionFlipFromRight], // change type accordingly
                     animations: {

                       // do your stuff
   },
                     completion: nil)
```

Comment: Solved. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Replace your ImageCapturingView with "capturePreviewView"

```
 UIView.transition(with: capturePreviewView, duration: 0.5, options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft, .allowAnimatedContent], animations: nil) { (finished) in
   //Code

    }
```

Perform any UI changes in mainQueue